# How to add -confirm:$false in a powershell hashtable?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

```
$cmdlet="Disable-RemoteMailBox"
$arguments = @{Identity=$identity;DomainController=$domaincontroller;Archive=""}
$command_args=""
$arguments.keys | ForEach-Object{
    $message = '-{0} {1} ' -f $_, $arguments[$_]
        $command_args+= $message
}
$result=& $cmdlet @arguments 2>&1
```

In the end this is executed:

```
Disable-RemoteMailBox -Identity abc@corp.com -DomainController dc.corp.local -Archive
```

but i need to add a confirm:$false

```
Disable-RemoteMailBox -Identity abc@corp.com -DomainController dc.corp.local -Archive -Confirm:$false
```

How to add this $false in the Hashtable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `$arguments` hashtable from:

```
$arguments = @{Identity=$identity;DomainController=$domaincontroller;Archive=""}
```

to

```
$arguments = @{Identity=$identity;DomainController=$domaincontroller;Archive="";Confirm=$false}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Mathias's concise answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68832173/4749264)

Excepting for the confirm functionality's integration with the `$ConfirmPreference` preference variable, the `-Confirm` common parameter can be looked at as a simple switch parameter. It is either present or not present.  However, PowerShell's internal type conversion engine will evaluate a `[Switch]` more like a `[Boolean]`  You can see this if you cast a `[Bool]` to a `[Switch]`.

`[Switch]$true` or `[Switch]$false` will return IsPresent True/False respectively.

If you specify `Confirm = $false` in a splatting hash table, the type coercion (casting) that occurs during the parameter binding will handle it correctly.  This is also true for any other switch parameter, even custom ones you define in your custom functions.  This type conversion is also noticiable when you need to evaluate a switch parameter internal to a function.

If I specify a switch parameter named `$Delete`

```
Param( [Switch]$Delete )
```

Then internally I can execute logic like:

```
If( $Delete -eq $true ) {
    # Delete the file or whatever...
}
```

Of course, you can shorten to:

```
If( $Delete ) {
    # Delete the file or whatever...
}
```

However, you don't need a deep understanding of PowerShell's type conversion system to use Boolean or Switch parameters in splatting hash tables. It's documented in [about_Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1#splatting-with-hash-tables). The first few lines will explain hash table splatting of switch parameters.